# how to play .flv video format using jplayer

Tags: video, format, flv, jplayer

I'm currently trying to give user the privilege to play video using jplayer. It supports these formats :- webmv, ogv, m4v. But it does not support .flv

I would really love to get some help with these using jplayer. But if anyone knows any media player plugin that support all or most video formats including .flv, i will be glad to know where and how to get it.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
   ogv: "video/<?php echo $get_vid; ?>",
   flv: "video/<?php echo $get_vid; ?>"
});
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "webmv, ogv, flv",
        size: {
            width: "640px",
            height: "360px",
            cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
        }
    });

});
//]]>
</script>
```

Just a little detail about it, the videos are fetched dynamically from the database and a lot of them are .flv

Would be very glad to get help with this...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your supplied value

```
    supplied: "flv",
```